# Acessing fields in a gtkmm ComboBoxText

Tags: c++, user-interface, textbox, gtkmm

I am having some troubles using the `get_active` text function on the `ComboBoxText` instances in my program. The error i get is

```
(out:4258): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_utf8_collate: assertion `str2 != NULL' failed.
```

What are some of the possible issues i might have with how i am using `ComboBoxText`?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is selected in the combo, you will get an empty string from `get_active_text()`.  It's probable that you are using that string later in a place where an empty string is not a legal value.